# Options other than the NSF for PhD level grants?

Tags: phd, funding, united-states

There is a big push in the PhD program I'm headed into for candidates to apply for NSF grants (in fact, one of the required classes for the first year is a class on writing grant proposals, and as a final project, every candidate submits an NSF proposal). I'm assuming this is the same for any Science/Math PhD program, as funding is tight for many departments, and a grant basically makes you free for the University.

Are there any other options for Science PhD-level grants I could apply for?

Comment: This seems to be a shopping question.

Comment: "I'm assuming this is the same for any Science/Math PhD program," No, most are not so well organized.

Comment: Perhaps this should be community wiki.

Comment: What type of science are you in? Physical, life, ect.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few government fellowships come to mind:

- [DoE Office of Science Graduate Student Research (SCGSR)](http://science.energy.gov/wdts/scgsr/)
- [DoD National Defense Science and Engineering Graduate Fellowship (NDSEG)](http://www.onr.navy.mil/Education-Outreach/undergraduate-graduate/NDSEG-graduate-fellowship.aspx)
- [DoD Science, Mathematics & Research for Transformation (SMART)](http://smart.asee.org/about/eligibility)

There are also many fellowships from industrial research labs that you could look into, depending on your field (Intel, IBM Research, Microsoft Research, Facebook, Nvidia, etc.)

Comment: Note that fellowship programs are more oriented toward support of the student, and expect application for the fellowship at the same time as applying to programs, while this question is about proposals written during the first year, presumably toward support of particular research.

Comment: It's worth noting that the DOE SCGF was unfortunately only funded in the years 2010 and 2012, and does not appear to be accepting applications.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget about:

- [NIH Individual National Research Service Award (NRSA) predoctoral training fellowships](http://www.ninds.nih.gov/funding/areas/training_and_career_development/pre-doctoral-fellowship.htm)

Answer (score 5):

I think all the answers given so far (and several others) are included in the list at gradschools.com.
Start with the list here:

- [Federally funded portable fellowships](http://www.gradschools.com/financial-aid/graduate-fellowships-scholarships/fellowships-for-graduate-students#Federally_Funded_Portable_Fellowships)

It includes DOE CSGF, NASA, DHS, CDC, NDSEG, and NIH.  Almost all the fellowships listed are primarily for STEM students.

A few of these are also relevant:

- [Portable Fellowships from Independent Organizations](http://www.gradschools.com/financial-aid/graduate-fellowships-scholarships/fellowships-for-graduate-students#Portable_Fellowships_from_Independent_Organizations)

In particular: Hertz, NPSC, and a couple of others that have more narrow eligibility requirements.

Answer (score 3):

For the international students, there aren't a lot of external funding opportunities. But do check out the HHMI international student fellowship. You can apply for it during your second or third year and it supports the student for the third to the fifth year. Unfortunately, only institutions with an HHMI investigator can nominate students for the fellowship, and only students in natural sciences are eligible.

Comment: For international students, there often are funding opportunities at the home country.

Comment: @vonbrand that's true without saying. But usually these opportunities come with strings attached so it's always nice to have alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Some other funding sources include:

- [The EPA STAR Graduate Fellowship](http://www.epa.gov/research-fellowships)
- [The Ford Foundation's Fellowship](http://nationalacademies.org/ford)
- [NSA Fellowships](https://www.nsa.gov/ia/academic_outreach/student_opportunities/)
- [Google Research](http://research.google.com/research-outreach.html#/research-outreach)
- [The Data Incubator](https://www.thedataincubator.com/)

If you want to work for a Federal Agency, I would suggest searching their webpages for Fellowships/Internships. Some state agencies might also offer fellowship/scholarship/internship opportunities.

**Note: Edited to add new fellowships that I learned about after the post**.